# Exemplo ScrollForm do Delphi não está funcionando na versão 10.2

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10, embarcadero

Tenho um App (Android) desenvolvido na versão Delphi 10.1, onde usei os exemplos do ScrollForm (para que o layout se mova junto com o teclado virtual android para não cobrir os edits), agora fui fazer deploy na versão atual (10.2) e simplesmente não funciona, testei o exemplo de novo e mesmo ele também não funciona, aconteceu isso com mais alguém? o que fez para resolver?

Comment: Foi desenvolvida uma classe para resolver esse problema, sugiro dar uma pesquisada por vkbdhelper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se já resolveu, mas sempre que preciso manipular teclado do Android eu utilizo a unit uKBForm disponível no repositório aqui: https://github.com/mobius1qwe/youtubefiles/tree/main/uKBForm

Segue um vídeo explicando como utilizar a unit no projeto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6pb3aPLKfw&t=1s

Passos para utilização:

- Adicione a unit ao projeto,
- Gere uma herança dela através do File > new > Other... e então selecione o KBForm na lista de Inheritables.
- Daí basta montar sua aplicação dentro do VSB herdado que você não precisa mais se preocupar com sobreposição do teclado.

Comment: Recomendo ler [este link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) para melhorar a sua resposta.